# Codeigniter4 how to call parent controller's constructor from derived class constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In Codeignter 4 we can't use constructor in BaseController. But the method initController() will do it. But how can call this method from derived controller's constructor?

My question is that `BaseController::is_allowed()` method will do all basic features that are commonly useful for all derived controller classes. But to work `BaseController::is_allowed()` , `BaseController::__construct()` should be execute before this. But as in CI-4, constructor is not allowed in `BaseController`. It can have `BaseController::initController()`.  But the problem is that this method will execute only after `DerivedClass::__construct()`.

I need to execute `BaseController::is_allowed()` before executing every derived class methods. So I call  `BaseController::is_allowed()` method in constructor of derived controllers. But derived class constructor executes before the execution of `BaseController::initController()`. So `BaseController::is_allowed()` not works.

> BaseController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\CLIRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\IncomingRequest;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public $request;

    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        
        // Doing all basic setups here that are needed to all other methods in this class.

        // This method will be called only after derivedClass::__construct().
        // But CI-4 not allows to use __construct() method in BaseController class.
        // This causes my problem.
    }

    function is_allowed()
    {
        // Provides all basic features for all derived controller classes.
        // But to work code in this method, initController() method should execute first.
    }
}
```

And the derived class as

> Users.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Users extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // BaseController::is_allowed() will provide all basic features for this controller.
        // To work this method, BaseController::initController() should execute.
        // But this will execute only after this ( __construct()) constuctor.
        // In Codeignier-3, BaseController::__construct() was possible.
        // It will execute before derived class constructor.
        $this->is_allowed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you try add `RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger` to construc params?

Comment: No, I need to get this thing. How I get these variables, because it is available in parent controller but not available its constructor. Derived class:: __construct() method will execute before the execution of parent::initController()

Comment: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/controllers.html#included-properties
The application’s main Request Instance is always available as a class property, `$this->request`.
From official documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your Users Controller should use the iniController and not the construct, like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface; 
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface; 
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Users extends BaseController
{
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);
        $this->is_allowed();
    }
}
```

However its a good practice to create your is_allowed function in your BaseController as a protected function, otherwise one might be able to access it via any url like site.com/users/is_allowed

I might even add that if the purpose of the is_allowed function is to check if the user has permission to do an action or even be in that controller your should look into [Filters](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/filters.html?highlight=filters) and not this

Comment: For login check I have used `Filters`. `is_allowed` provides basic features for derived classes and some check up. So it can't be in `Filter`

Comment: To work your code I need to put
`use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;`
`use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;`
`use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;`
Below the `namespace`

Comment: @ShihabuRahman added that to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> In Codeignter 4 we can't use constructor in controllers.

You don't use a typical constructor in the *BaseController* class, you can still use constructors in your App/Controller classes.

You do not need to manually make a call to `initController`, that is done for you during the bootstrap process. Remove that line from your `App\Controllers\Users` constructor function.

Comment: I have edited my question with more explanations. This was my coding structure I used with **Codeigniter 3**.  But in **CI-4**, I understood that, I should rewrite my coding structure and it is only the solution. Yes?

Comment: @ShihabuRahman The `initController` method that exists inside the default `App\Controllers\BaseController` is invoked during the bootstrap process; all of your Controller classes should extend this `BaseController` class but they do not need to manually invoke `initController` in any way. All the accepted answer does is initialize the Controller twice. Functions you define within the `BaseController` class will automatically be available to any class that extends it; if for some reason you have an identical method inside your Controller, you would have to use `parent::method()`